# how does SEO index pages with ajax loaded content

Tags: ajax, seo

i'm a little confused about how search engines will treat this two cases:

1. i have a page "all articles" which has previews of recent articles( some text plus read more) and a page for each article, will this be considered as duplicate content by search engines?
2. when a search engine indexes a page does it index also the content on the page that is loaded via ajax? (in my case the page "all articles" load the previews of articles via ajax.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, no it will not be treated as duplicate content, those are just previews.

For the second one , search engines DO index Ajax content if they are crawlable.

You can make sure they are crawlable by ensuring your site has theese tags:

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more

Comment: thanks Webrankgraphics for your answer, for the first question i wonder if i just have to block the page "all articles" from being indexed because it is just previews page and for each article there is already a page, what do you think?

Comment: The link referred to here was officially deprecated as of October 2015, and they recommend that you do not implement these tags anymore.

Comment: Google guide is deprecated since October 2015.